# Number of Divisor

Tags: divisibility

How to find the Number of divisors of a number 'n' that are also divisible by another number 'k' without looping through all the divisors of n?
I tried the following:

Stored powers of all prime factors of n in an associative array A and did similarly for k, stored the powers of all primes factors in array B.

```
    ans = 1
    for a in A:    // Here a is the prime factor and A[a] gives its power
        ans *= if( a is present in B ) ? 1 : A[a] + 1
    print ans
```

Note : It is not homework.

Comment: You want divisors $d$ of both $n$ and $k$. Consider what $\gcd(n,k)$ means, and its relationship to each such $d$. Calculating the $\gcd$ is fairly quick.

Comment: @Kirk, I think sabari wants $k$ dividing $d$, not $d$ dividing $k$.

Comment: Hm.. from the code he provided I got the impression otherwise (A being the prime-power factors of $n$ and B being the prime-power factors of $k$), although to be honest I don't entirely follow the code, as it is in an unfamiliar language for me. @sabari, can you clarify?

Comment: @KirkBoyer Yeah, Gerry is right. I want the divisors of n that are divisible by k. That is k dividing d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any divisor of $n$ that is itself divisible by $k$ can be written as $d k$, where $d$ is a divisor of $\frac nk$. Hence their number is exactly the number of divisors of $\frac nk$.

Of course we need $k$ to be a divsor of $n$ for this to make sense at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood the mistake I made. Out of curiosity , may I ask a small variant of the above.. is it possible to find the "number of divisors of n which are not divisible by k" by simple methods?

Comment: I got the idea for the above variant also.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is compute $\sigma_0(n/k)$, where $\sigma_0(m)$ is the divisor function, which counts the number of divisors of $m$. The reason of this is that 
$$
k \, | \, m \, | \, n \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad m = kd \quad \text{and} \quad d \, | \, n/k.
$$
This is quite easy to prove, I'll leave it up to you. Now to compute $\sigma_0(n/k)$, one can show that $\sigma$ is a multiplicative function, because $f(n) = 1$ is multiplicative, hence
$$
\sigma_0(n) = \sum_{d \, | \, n} f(d)
$$
also is (well-known theorem in number theory that $\sum_{d \, | \, n} f(d)$ is multiplicative when $f$ is). Therefore, since $\sigma_0(p^{\alpha}) = \alpha+1$, you have 
$$
\sigma_0(n) = \prod_{p \, | , n} (\alpha(n,p) + 1)
$$
where $\alpha(n,p)$ stands for the greatest power of $p$ dividing $n$. In other words, all you have to do is factor $n/k$ and use the factorization to compute $\sigma_0(n/k)$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: $\sigma$ is usually used for the sum of the divisors; $\tau$ or $d$ for the number of divisors.

Comment: Right ; I forgot to write $\sigma_0$. The function $\sigma_k$ is usually for the sum of the $k^{\text{th}}$ powers. Thanks for noticing.